# How to get attributes by attribute set ID in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set

How can I **retrieve a list of attributes and values by given attribute set ID** in Magento 2?

Comment: Did you find the solution, Please update the answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **`Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeManagementInterface` service contract class**:

```
$attributeManagementInterface->getAttributes(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, $attributeSetId);
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer ?